# Redirect www.example.com and https://www.example.com into https://example.com

Tags: .htaccess

i have a URL called https://example.com

I would like to redirect request from www.example.com and https://www.example.com into https://example.com in .htaccess file.

Could guys please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this rule on the top of your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect all www requests to https non www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Redirect all other http requests (ex. http://example.com) to https non www
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```